# Static variable accessed from null variable

Tags: java, static

Why is a null reference exception not thrown when I try to print the value of a static field value from an uninitialized instance of a class.

I expected a Null reference exception in the following code:

```
public class Check {

  static int i=1;

  public static void main(String []args)
  {
     Check ch = null;
     System.out.print(ch.i);
  }

}
```

Produces output as: `1`.

Answer (score 2):

In your snippet, `i` is static that means it may not need to be instantiated that means the default constructor need not be called as:

```
Check ch= new Check();
```

as `i` is `static` only a reference will suffice. Like you did,

```
Check ch = null;
```

So doing,

```
System.out.println(ch.i);
```

will print the value of `i` that is 1 from static context

Answer (score 1):

Given that `i` is `static` (it can be accessed through the class directly, no need to use an instance for it), in the code **`ch.i`**, the compiler checks for the type of the reference of **`ch`** (`Check`) and use it for accessing the variable `i` instead of using the class instance. This mean `null` (the instance) is not used at all (thus we don't get any exception).

That's it, the output of `Check.i` is `1`.

Comment: That clears my thoughts, about reference null and period operator in this case.Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Because i is a static variable, it does not matter whether its value is obtained from an object or from the class.

See the note here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html